# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\pi} \lfloor \cot x\rfloor dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-verification

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \lfloor \cot x\rfloor dx\;,$ Where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ is floor function of $x$.

$\bf{My\; Solution ::}$ Let $\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \lfloor \cot x\rfloor dx$

$\displaystyle 2I= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\lfloor \cot x \rfloor + \lfloor \cot (\pi -x)\rfloor\right)  dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\lfloor \cot x\rfloor + \lfloor -\cot x \rfloor  \right)dx =\int_{0}^{\pi} (-1) dx=- \pi$,

(as $\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor -x
\rfloor =-1, x\notin{I}$)

$\displaystyle I=-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Could anyone Please check and told if there is any fault.

Thanks

Comment: You have the problem that the integral doesn't exist. You need to make it a principal value integral. _Then_ you can use the symmetry. (And a typo, you mean $\lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor -x\rfloor = -1$ for $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a problem from Brilliant.Org.